# vairable doesnt pass into mysql through python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to pass varible into mysql but it wont insert into the table and no error occur in python.

```
db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "1234", "vehiclerecord")
cursor = db.cursor() 
params =('7',vehicle_no,'2')

sql ="""INSERT INTO vehiclerecord.v_entry (v_id, v_no, v_type) VALUES (%S,%S,%S)""",(params)

try:      
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()

except:
      db.rollback()

db.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
sql ="""INSERT INTO vehiclerecord.v_entry (v_id, v_no, v_type) VALUES (%S,%S,%S)""",(params)

cursor.execute(sql)
```

You should:

```
sql ="""INSERT INTO vehiclerecord.v_entry (v_id, v_no, v_type) VALUES (%S,%S,%S)"""

cursor.execute(sql, params)
```